# How to make a sprite disappear with various animations on its click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2D. I am making a simple game for iPhone in which I want my sprite to disappear with some animation. Till now I can make it disappear with the following code:-

```
-(void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{ 

    for (CCSprite *sprite in targets)  
    {

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) 
        {
            NSLog(@"sprite was touched");

            [sprite.parent removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"pop.wav"];
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];

        }
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for( UITouch *touch in touches )
    {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

        [self selectSpriteForTouch:location];
        NSLog(@"touch was detected");
    }   
}
```

Now I want the sprite to disappear with some animation or any effect. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, this would make your sprite shrink until it disappears then remove it from it's parent:

```
-(void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
    ...
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation))
    {
        [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
            [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.4 scale:0],
            [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSprite:) object:sprite],
            nil]];
            ...//play audio etc
    }
    ....
}

-(void) removeSprite:(CCSprite*) s
{
    [s.parent removeChild:s cleanup:YES];
}
```

For other actions, try `CCMoveTo` or `CCJumpTo` or `CCRotateBy`. You can run several actions at once, so above the `runAction:` line I provided, try another `[sprite runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.4 angle:360]]`

Comment: Thanks James, your suggestion was helpful. To be specific, i am building an app in which balloons blast when touched. I want an explosion kind of effect or something which would look more appropriate.

Comment: You're likely to want to use a sequence of frames to achieve the blast animation. Have a look at [CCAnimation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_animation.html) for the coding and [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/) for the creation of spritesheets.